# Building LFS - Error at 5.7: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support

Tags: linux, glibc, linux-from-scratch

I am about to build my first `Linux` from scratch....
I've done everything exactly as it's written in the book - at least i think i did.

Now, building the `glibc` results to the following problem:

```
checking for .preinit_array/.init_array/.fini_array support... no
configure: error: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support.
```

With this message, *glibc-2.18/configure* tool breaks up
in the config.log it says at some point:

```
collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'
```

I guess these errors are related.

I am running a *64-bit* machine. some people with similar errors said, that this might be the cause of the error - but that should not be, right?

I hope that some of you can help me with this, or at least explain what's going on there.

I have the `ld` and the `readelf` in my */tools* folder, why isn't it found?

Comment: Does $LFS is well defined ? you can check `echo $LFS`?

Comment: echo $LFS => /mnt/lfs
maybe i missed some other variables that point to the ld or something but i am not aware which...

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this, I just got same error!

Comment: Unfortunately not, i retried a different LFS version on a 32 bit machine and that worked. But this cannot be the solution...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same `configure: error: Need linker with .init_array/.fini_array support.` error while building `glibc` on a x86_64 grsec linux box. In my case the perp was the `CFLAGS` environment variable (set in `~/local/share/config.site`) and in particular the switch for position independent code, `-fPic` which was causing this problem. Its a more-or-less known bug.